# Перебор массива

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте, не могу придумать нормальное решение, есть многомерный массив, в котором несколько почти одинаковых массивов, у них разный только id или name
вот дамп массива:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "тег1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "тег2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "тег3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(28) "Всё о интернете"
    ["text"]=>
    string(41) "Тут просто сама статья"
    ["date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "тег4"
  }
}
```

Нужно превратить в нормальный вид, то есть где совпадает id, нужно как-то склеить все ["name"] и разделить через запятую 
Понимаю тут перебором, но нормального решение не могу пока найти

[UPD]
Решение:

```
$result = array();
$curid = $arr[0]["id"];
$cnt = 0;

foreach ($arr as $k=>$v)
{

    if ($v["id"] == $curid && $k !=0)
    {
        $result[$cnt]["id"]=$v["id"];
        $result[$cnt]["title"]=$v["title"];
        $result[$cnt]["text"]=$v["text"];
        $result[$cnt]["date"]=$v["date"];
        $result[$cnt]["name"].=','.$v["name"];
    }
    else
    {
        $cnt++;
        $result[$cnt]["id"]=$v["id"];
        $result[$cnt]["title"]=$v["title"];
        $result[$cnt]["text"]=$v["text"];
        $result[$cnt]["date"]=$v["date"];
        $result[$cnt]["name"]=$v["name"];
        $curid=$v["id"];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочая функция:

```
function glueDuplicates($input = array())
{
    $data = array_values($input);
    $pKeys = array("id", "name");
    $iCount = count($data) - 1;

    foreach ($data as $v) {
        $iKeys = array_keys($v);
        if (!is_array($v) || ($pKeys !== array_intersect($pKeys, $iKeys))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    unset($v);

    for ($current = $iCount; $current > 0; --$current) {
        $prev = $current - 1;
        if ($data[$current]["id"] === $data[$prev]["id"]) {
            $data[$prev]["name"] .= empty($data[$prev]["name"]) ? "" : ", ";
            $data[$prev]["name"] .= $data[$current]["name"];
            unset($data[$current]);
        }
    }
    return array_values($data);
}
```

Тестовые входные данные:

```
$testinput = array(
    0 => array(
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "Интернет",
        "text" => "Текст текст текст",
        "date" => "1371186330",
        "name" => "тег1",
    ),
    1 => array(
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "Интернет",
        "text" => "Текст текст текст",
        "date" => "1371186330",
        "name" => "тег2",
    ),
    2 => array(
        "id" => "1",
        "title" => "Интернет",
        "text" => "Текст текст текст",
        "date" => "1371186330",
        "name" => "тег3"
    ),
    3 => array(
        "id" => "2",
        "title" => "Всё о интернете",
        "text" => "Тут просто сама статья",
        "date" => "0",
        "name" => "тег4"
    )
);
```

Пример использования:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(glueDuplicates($testinput));
echo "</pre>";
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Интернет
            [text] => Текст текст текст
            [date] => 1371186330
            [name] => тег1, тег2, тег3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Всё о интернете
            [text] => Тут просто сама статья
            [date] => 0
            [name] => тег4
        )

)
```